# In Pygame, why am I unable to make part of an image transparent?

Tags: python, pygame

I have an image of a red ball on a blue background saved as a BMP file. There are only two colors used in the image: red (255, 0, 0) and blue (0, 0, 255). I wrote the following Pygame test program to isolate the problem. It simply loads an image, sets the upper-left pixel's color as the transparent color, and blits it to the screen. It's about as simple as it gets, but I can't get it to work.

```
import pygame

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    size = (640, 400)
    screenSurface = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    ballSurface = pygame.image.load("ball.bmp")

    transparentColor = ballSurface.get_at((0, 0))
    ballSurface.set_colorkey(transparentColor)

    screenSurface.blit(ballSurface, ballSurface.get_rect())
    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.time.wait(30000)
```

I've tried passing each color manually into `set_colorkey()` to no avail. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: made a red circle with a blue bg and it worked fine it just showed the red circle no blue

Answer (score 2):

Ugh! After messing with this for a really long time, I finally figured it out. All I had to do was change `load(...)` to `load(...).convert()`! Now my hair is all ripped out.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    size = (640, 400)
    screenSurface = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    ballSurface = pygame.image.load("ball.bmp")

//You need to loop through each pixel.

    for each x in range (0, 640)
        for each y in range (o, 400)

            pixel =getPixel (x,y)

//algorithm follows
//get each pixel
//find it's color
//change the individual color of each pixel

    transparentColor = ballSurface.get_at((0, 0))
    pixel.set_colorkey(transparentColor)

    screenSurface.blit(ballSurface, ballSurface.get_rect())
    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.time.wait(30000)
```